# Using Column Heading as lookup for Sheet Name

Tags: vba, excel, indexing, match

I want to lookup a value for a certain product code (column a) as it corresponds to a week (numerically listed in row 1). The week codes (in row 1) refer to a workbook that has a sheet for each week, exactly as it appears here. I want to go to that workbook, access the correct sheet, find the product code, and pull the corresponding cell from column L. I'm not sure how to write this.
I have about 500 week codes and 500 product codes, so I'm thinking a macro is needed.

An example if it's helpful: In cell B2 I want to find the data from sheet 40111, column L on "Combined Performance Tracking.xlsx" that corresponds to NPPP.

[image: worksheet]

I have written this so far, but my index match is singled out as an issue when I run it. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
Sub populate()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim count
Dim count2
Dim stock_code
Dim rep
Dim sheet_name As String

ws = Sheets("Sheet3")

For count = 2 To 140
    sheet_name = ws.Cells(1, count)

    For count2 = 2 To 873
        stock_code = ws.Cells(count2, 1)
        Workbooks("Combined Performance tracking.xlsx").Activate
            For rep = 1 To (Worksheets.count)
                 If sheet_name = Sheets(rep).Name Then
                        index($a$5:$az$800, match(stock_code, $A$5:$A$800, 0), match("uber", $a$5:$az$5, 0)
                    ActiveCell.Select
                    ActiveCell.Copy
                    Workbooks("Jody Project Final.xlsm").Activate
                    Worksheets("sheet3").Cells(count2, count).Activate
                    ActiveCell.Select
                    ActiveCell.Paste
                        End If
            Next
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: the index is not proper syntax in many ways, you also need to assign it a variable to get the result. also, you *may* be able to use a formula with cell dragging (but a macro may be more efficient)

Comment: You will have to incorporate the volatile [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd) into your [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pair to use it as a native function but you can build something with a [WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx)..

Comment: also are you positive that sheet will exist in the workbook?

Comment: Yes, the sheet will exist. I pulled these column headings using a macro that copied the exact sheet name. How do I incorporate an indirect function into that?

Comment: What's this line doing? `sheet_name=wsdata.cells(1, count)` Where did `wsdata` get declared?  Or do you mean `sheet_name=ws.cells(1,count)`? Also, add `Option Explicit` to the **very** top (above `Sub populate()`) to force you to declare all variables you're using.

Comment: I was trying to reference the name of the sheet I am looking for. That sheet name is in row 1. The count should reference the column the name is in. Ie sheet 7011 should be wsdata.cells(1,3).

Comment: Also, I did forget to declare wsdata, but its redundant with ws. So, ws.cells should work

Comment: @ScottHoltzman 
Is this better syntax?

`application.worksheetfunction.index(sheets("Sheet3").Range("a5:az800"), application.worksheetfunction.match(stock_code, sheets(sheet_name).range("A5:A800"), 0), application.worksheetfunction.match("uber", sheets(sheet_name).range("a5:az5"), 0))`

Answer (score 0):

SQL might give slightly better performance by I don't know have to join tables from different workbooks with the ADO. I prefer to use a scripting dictionary when comparing 1 table to many tables in Excel.    
(500 weeks) * (500 products) = 25000 multiply that by the number of operations  per lookup and assignment, it's probably at over 100,000 operations. [EXCEL VLOOKUP VS INDEX MATCH VS SQL VS VBA](http://analystcave.com/excel-vlookup-vs-index-match-vs-sql-performance/) bench tests the various methods.  Based on that article my macro should take 3 to 7 secs.  Let me know if it work and how long it takes to execute.

```
Sub FillProductPrices()
    ToggleEvents False

    Dim dProducts
    Dim wsLookup As Worksheet
    Dim arSheetNames, arProducts, arValues, arLookUp
    Dim x As Long, y As Long, count As Long, i As Long
    Dim k As String, SheetName As String
    Dim wbTarget As Worksheet
    Dim wbDataSource As Workbook

    Set wbDataSource = Workbooks.Open("Combined Performance tracking.xlsx")

    Set wbTarget = Sheets("Sheet3")

    Set dProducts = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With wbTarget
        arProducts = .Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Value
        arSheetNames = .Range("B1", .Range("B1").End(xlToRight)).Value
        count = UBound(arProducts, 1)
    End With

    For i = 1 To count
        k = UCase(Trim( arProducts(i, 1) ))
        If Not dProducts.Exists(k) Then dProducts.Add k, i
    Next

    For y = 1 To UBound(arSheetNames, 2)
        On Error Resume Next
        SheetName = arSheetNames(1, y)
        Set wsLookup = wbDataSource.Worksheets(SheetName)
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            With wsLookup
                ReDim arValues(1 To count, 1 To 1) As Double
                arProducts = .Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Value
                arLookUp = .Range("L2", .Range("L" & Rows.count).End(xlUp)).Value
            End With

            For x = 1 To count
                k = UCase(Trim( arProducts(x, 1) ))
                If dProducts.Exists(k) Then
                    i = dProducts(k)
                    arValues(i, 1) = arLookUp(x, 1)
                End If
            Next

            wbTarget.Cells(2, y + 1).Resize(count) = arValues
        Else
            Debug.Print SheetName & " not found"
            Err.Clear
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

    Next

    ToggleEvents True
End Sub

Sub ToggleEvents(EnableEvents As Boolean)
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = EnableEvents
        .Calculation = IIf(True, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be a ton closer than I was. When I run it, I get zeros in many columns. Columns are either entirely blank or have zeros all the way through the last product code. Any idea what to do?

Comment: If a column is blank then the `Worksheets("Week Code")` wasn't found.  Zeros indicate product codes not found.  Check the Column header and make sure that it exactly matches the sheet name in `Combined Performance tracking.xlsx`. I just added `UCase(Trim([product codes]))` to make it case insensitive and remove any spaces.  If there is a zero value than try to lookup the product code on that week's worksheet.  Let me know what you find and we can try to adjust the code.